# Create multiple divs using ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I want to create 'n' red blocks with text (n here means the number of elements in array). But, I am getting a blank page.

```
<html>
  <body>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
    <style>
      .card-main {
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        border: 1px solid red;
        background-color: red;
      }
    </style>
    <!-- look here start --> 
    <div class="card-main" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl" ng-repeat="x in type">
      <p>{{x}}</p> 
    </div>
    <!-- look here end -->
    <script>
      var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
      app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
        $scope.type = ["Any", "T1", "T2", "T3"];
        $scope.state = ["Any", "S1", "S2"];
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

`ng-repeat` has very high priority, it is applied before `ng-controller` e.g.

```
<div ng-repeat="..." ng-controller="..."
```

will render several divs with several controller instances, not several divs inside one controller.

To start, just put ng-app, ng-controller and ng-repeat on different elements:

```
<div ng-app ...
  <div ng-controller ...
    <div ng-repeat ...
```

Comment: This is great! Got the idea now